# vim syntax scripts "sourcing" another, but only for matching lines

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a vim syntax script and I want to be able to make lines matching a certain pattern, say, '`^>`', "source" or imitate the markdown syntax highlighting.

Is there a way to do this at the syntax script level?  Do I need to just copy and paste it in manually and make the proper adjustments?  Does this require a modeline on the actual file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `:help :syn-include`. It allows you to import an existing syntax (like e.g. *markdown*) into a syntax cluster in your own syntax, and then you can assign syntax regions (if I understand you correctly, that would be a region starting with `/^>/` and ending at the end of the line `/$/`) to it.

Note that success isn't guaranteed; you need some collaboration from the included syntax. (For example, if the markdown syntax anchors its patterns at `^`, but now it's included behind the `>` prefix, it won't match any more.) In the worst case, you have to modify the included syntax or copy it completely into your own syntax.